# External list in SharePoint 2010 with unique item permissions

Tags: 2010, bcs, external-list

Is there any way to set permission for bdc items within external list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any ability to set security on individual items in an external list. Your best bet is to try to handle this on the server side, perhaps passing the current username into a stored procedure for your get & get-list operations, and handling security in the SP logic.